# Sending mail from a java app without using an external SMTP server

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, email

JavaMail requires that you specify an external SMTP server when sending mail. I want to have my java app send email directly without having to use an external SMTP server such as postfix or sendmail.

Can anyone recommend a library which provides this kind of functionality? 
Ive done some googling and have come up with nothing.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using an external SMTP server? Typically when you deliver your message to your SMTP server it then relays the message to the mail server for the domain of the email recipient. The alternative really is to look up the mail server for the receiving domain (via DNS) and then deliver to that server directly.

Comment: In the end I just used postfix :(

Answer (score 4):

It's not trivial to send mail yourself. To start with, you have to deal with DNS (MX records), queuing, connection management and maybe signing (DKIM). So you wouldn't find any light-weight library like JavaMail to do this.

Your best bet is JAMES,

http://james.apache.org/